# Partial summing and calculation with data from another table

Tags: r, dataframe, sum

My goal is to perform temporal disaggregation of precipitation using two different datasets:

1) Containing data on day&hour of observation and a column with precipitation observation values, 
2) The other dataset containing information on daily sum precipitation.

Firstly I would like to create a new column *Percent* for the first dataset which will contain proportional distribution throughout a day of rainfall from column *Value*. Afterward, I want to take a corresponding (according to the date) sum of precipitation from the other dataset and disaggregate it temporarily using the newly created column *Percent* and create a column like *NewValue*.

I want to do it automatically as I have 3 years of observations.

Please find below a reproducible example of the results I would like to achieve:

```
dates = seq(as.POSIXct("2015-1-1 23:00"), as.POSIXct("2015-1-2 23:00"), by = "hour")
Value = c(0,0.15,0.1,0,0,0.3,0.4,0.5,0,0,0,0,0,0,0.6,0.1,0,0,0,0,0,0.3,0.5,0,0)
Percent = c(0,0.05,0.03,0,0,0.1,0.14,0.17,0,0,0,0,0,0,0.2,0.03,0,0,0,0,0,0.1,0.17,0,0)
NewValue = c(0,0.1,0.07,0,0,0.2,0.27,0.34,0,0,0,0,0,0,0.41,0.07,0,0,0,0,0,0.2,0.34,0,0)

DATA = data.frame(dates, Value, Percent, NewValue)
```

In the example above I took for 2015-1-1 the daily precipitation as equal to 0, and for the other day equal to 2 mm.

Comment: You have not posted *the other dataset*. As for the first calculation, just do `DATA$Percent <- with(DATA, Value/sum(Value))`. In your example the result of this is further `round(DATA$Percent, 2)`.

Comment: It is almost correct, but I want to to the summing of precipitation by days - not for the whole data.

Answer (score 0):

I do not understand how `NewValue` is calculated and yo udo not give the input dataset, so I have to create my own data.

```
# hourly precip
d1 <- data.frame(dates=seq(as.POSIXct("2015-1-1 01:00"), 
                 as.POSIXct("2015-1-3 23:00"), by = "hour"), precip=runif(71))
# calc d2 : not needed in your case
d2 <- ddply(d1, .(day=as.Date(dates)), summarize, precipsum=sum(precip))

# calc relative precip
d1$day <- as.Date(d1$dates)
out <- merge(d1, d2, by='day')
out$Percent <- out$precip / out$precipsum
```

Comment: The *Percent* column should be calculated for each day separately - giving in total value equal to 1 for the whole day. Afterward, I want to multiply the hourly distribution of *Percent* by the daily sum from other table (d2). This is how I want to get *NewValue*.

Comment: The code above already calculates the `Percent` column by day. I still don't get the meaning of `NewValue`. `NewValue = Percent * precipsum`? That would lead to `NewValue = precip`